# Display multiple values in separate rows with view that uses Search API

Tags: 8, views, search

Yesterday I asked [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/304121/changing-how-to-group-by) question, but after realizing the issue was specific to my view relying on an indexed field using the Search API module I wanted to make another post getting more specific help.

So I have a content type, "Person," that uses an entity reference to assign each person a program. I'm trying to make a "People" page for my site that groups the people by said program that they are in (ex. Human Resources, Engineering, Design, etc. etc.)

What the view does when grouping by Program is this:

Engineering, Design:

- Carlyn Beres

What I want it to do instead is this:

Engineering:

- Carlyn Beres

Design:

- Carlyn Beres

Unchecking the "Display all values in the same row" doesn't change it, and when adding "Aggregated Fields" as an indexed item in my Search API the only options I get are Union, Concatenate, Count, Sum, First, Last.

None of these options allow me to display fields with multiple values in separate rows.

Anything I'm missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: While not an ideal solution or even possible in some cases (e.g if the view has filters that make it impossible), I've worked around some grouping issues like this by creating my view to display the entity that I'm grouping by, and then displaying a view mode of that entity that shows the data I want. E.g. Create my view to display Programs and display a view mode of Programs that shows the Program's people.